# Como utilizar uma DLL não gerenciada no Bot Framework da Microsoft?

Tags: c#, c++, framework, dll, microsoft

Quero fazer um bot para facebook utilizando o Bot Framework da Microsoft (C#) e também utilizar uma ferramenta chamada ChatScript, que é escrita em C++.

Transformei o chatscript em uma DLL e a chamei em um console application em C#, que deu certo.

Quando tento fazer a mesma coisa em um projeto do bot framework, recebo System.StackOverflow quando chamo a DLL. O que pode ser?

Obs: o chatscript.dll está dentro da pasta bin junto com o Bot Application.dll gerado pelo projeto.

```
public static int InitSystem(int argc, SWIGTYPE_p_p_char argv, string unchangedPath, string readonlyPath, string writablePath) {
int ret = ChatScriptPINVOKE.InitSystem__SWIG_0(argc, SWIGTYPE_p_p_char.getCPtr(argv), unchangedPath, readonlyPath, writablePath);
return ret;  }

[global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("chatscript.dll", EntryPoint="CSharp_ChatScript_InitSystem__SWIG_0")]
public static extern int InitSystem__SWIG_0(int jarg1, global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef jarg2, string jarg3, string jarg4, string jarg5);
```

Comment: Seria bastante útil incluir o stacktrace da exceção...

Comment: A proposito, vc pode experimentar o [RiveScript](https://www.rivescript.com/about), que possui um interpretador feito em [C#](https://www.rivescript.com/interpreters)

Answer (score 0):

Olá, experimenta trocar a assinatura do método de:

```
[global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("chatscript.dll", EntryPoint="CSharp_ChatScript_InitSystem__SWIG_0")]
public static extern int InitSystem__SWIG_0(int jarg1, global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef jarg2, string jarg3, string jarg4, string jarg5);
```

Para:

```
[global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("chatscript.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint="CSharp_ChatScript_InitSystem__SWIG_0")]
public static extern int InitSystem__SWIG_0(int jarg1, IntPtr jarg2, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)] string jarg3, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)] string jarg4, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)] string jarg5);
```

Há alguns problemas em relação a utilização de string na passagem de parâmetros quando se utiliza DLL. Tive um problema parecido e corrigi dessa forma. Além disso, quando preciso manusear algum argumento utilizo ponteiros, por isso o tipo IntPtr.

Lembrando que em relação a string há outros tipos que pode utilizar ao invés do AnsiBStr. Esse eu utilizei em um DLL feita em Delphi, pode ser que para você seja necessário outro tipo.

Algo mais que pode estar faltando é o CallingConvention que no caso de DLLs construídas em C/C++, geralmente utiliza-se o tipo Cdecl.

Boa sorte!